# Handling Session Timeout Across Multiple GeneXus Applications with GAM and SSO

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, genexus, genexus-gam

I am working with two GeneXus .NET web applications that utilize the GeneXus Access Module (GAM) for authentication purposes (authorization is not the focus of this issue). These applications share the same repository and are configured with Single Sign-On (SSO).

The SSO functionality works as expected for login and logout actions across both applications. However, I am encountering an issue with session management. Specifically, when a session timeout occurs in one application leading to an automatic disconnection, the user remains connected in the other application. This situation can result in a single user being associated with two different active sessions across the applications.

My question is: Is there a way to detect a session timeout in one application and subsequently terminate all active sessions for that user across all connected GAM applications? I am seeking a solution that ensures consistent session management and user experience in a multi-application environment with shared GAM authentication.